# Connection between SELECT policy and PATCH API? PATCH request doesn't work due to SELECT policy

Tags: supabase, row-level-security

There is this table "customer" and it has "is_deleted" column.
I did to use it for [soft deletetion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soft_deletion).

And I set policy like below so that I don't have to add `is_deleted = false` condition everytime I select or join customer table.

```sql
  CREATE POLICY "can view customer" ON "public"."customer" USING (((is_deleted = false) AND (EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM admin_user WHERE (admin_user.uid = uid())))));
```

But PATCH request which updates "is_deleted" column doesn't work with this policy.

```js
export const softDeleteCustomer = async(id: number) => {
    await supabaseClient.from('customer').update({
      is_deleted: true
    }).eq('id', id);
}
```

I get an error saying It's violating row-level security.

```json
{
  "code":"42501",
  "details":null,
  "hint":null,
  "message":"new row violates row-level security policy for table \"customer\""
}
```

So I just removed is_deleted part in policy and it's working.
But I don't get it.

What is the problem of it?

What I'm trying to is not to select table but to update table.
Why SELECT policy above is preventing updating is_delete column?

Answer (score 0):

> Why SELECT policy above is preventing updating is_delete column?

Your policy is not only affecting SELECT but all commands. You'd need to add `FOR SELECT` to be scoped for SELECT:

```sql
CREATE POLICY "can view customer" ON "public"."customer" FOR SELECT --..
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html#SQL-CREATEPOLICY-SUMMARY